# Naming Preference for class fields in C#?

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

I have seen several naming conventions used for fields in C#.  They are:

**Underscore**

```
public class Foo
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
}
```

**This**

```
public class Foo
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
        set { this.name = value; }
    }
}
```

**Member Prefix**

```
public class Foo
{
    private string m_name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return m_name; }
        set { m_name = value; }
    }
}
```

Which do you prefer?  Is there a different way you prefer to do it?  Just curious to know what others feel is a best practice.

Comment: Dup with many, including: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450238/to-underscore-or-to-not-to-underscore-that-is-the-question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111605/what-kind-of-prefix-do-you-use-for-member-variables, etc

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833811/underscore-prefix-on-member-variables-intellisense (many, many, more...)

Comment: Agreed.  Somehow, I didn't find them when searching.  Also voting to close.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762025/

Answer (score 1):

I usually use:

```
public class Foo
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
}
```

just removed the this. since it's rather redundant

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to pick one, and be consistent.

I prefer "*", personally. "m*" has always seemed to me to make the "memberness" seem to be something special, as though it were for the benefit of developers coming from a background where no "members" exist. Sort of the same with "this.". I'd prefer just "name" instead.

Answer (score 0):

1) This is a purely stylistic/subjective question, so one of these is, in general, as good as another.  (I qualify that because the last time I answered a question like this, even with a nearly identical qualification, I had all kinds of people voting me down and telling me I was wrong.)

2)  I use the `this` method.  It's the default technique used by StyleCop, and I don't have any other source analysis tool available to me at the moment.  It's perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I always use what you call the **this** style, though I won't religiously use `this.`