# Custom Naming Style Options in Resharper For Backing Fields

Tags: .net, naming-conventions, resharper

The coding standard in my organization is for private fields to be lowerCamelCase but backing fields used by properties to be prefixed with an underscore (`_`).  Is there a way to add a rule just for backing fields in the [Resharper Naming Style](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Options__Languages__Visual_Basic__NET__VB_Naming_Style.html) tool.

Here's the Naming Rule Editor:
[image: resharper]

I'd rather this error not show up for local variables
[image: rename]

Examples in VB and C#:

**VB:**

```vb
Public Class Employee

    'Should be lowerCamelCase
    Private useCode As String = "NEW"

    'should be _lowerCamelCase
    Private _name As String

    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _name = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

**C#:**

```cs
public class Employee
{

    //Should be lowerCamelCase
    private string useCode = "NEW";

    //should be _lowerCamelCase
    private string _name;

    public string Name {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

}
```

Whether you [agree or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852433/naming-preference-for-class-fields-in-c) with this naming convention, is there a way to ask reshaper to enforce this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to enforce naming rules for backing fields in ReSharper, but you can add multiple rules for entity kind.

[image]

With this settings applied, ReSharper will allow you to have fields with and without underscore prefix.

Comment: That's perfect!  I'm so anal about getting resharper suggestions down to a minimum.  I like that it's enforcing both rules and it's up to me to make sure its the correct one.